# Rails Devise uninitialized constant Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My Rails version is 3.2.12. I use following commands to create users authentications:

```
rails generate devise:install
rails generate devise users
rake db:migrate
```

and following are my routes

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)       devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)      devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)  devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format) devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)      devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)        devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)       devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)          devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#destroy
```

But i still cant register new users or login into app even though user email and password are saved on db. Following are errors that i got:

```
NameError in Devise::RegistrationsController#create
uninitialized constant Model
```

Where i might be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this to change this line for devise.rb

config.sign_out_via = :delete

to

config.sign_out_via = :get

It works for me

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your routes,

devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "devise/registrations"} do
    get '/register' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
end